# How are 'positive' and 'negative' determined in Recall formula for machine learning?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, precision-recall

In Python scikitlearn there's a function called 'sklearn.metrics.recall_score' (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html), which is calculated by TP/(TP+FN).

In my unsupervised classification model I am classifying emails into 2 classes: 1 or -1. So my question is how does the 'recall_score' function know whether label '1' is 'positive' or label '-1' is 'negative' since I didn't specify which is which? If the model treats '1' as positive, the result for recall will be different from if the model treats '-1' as positive.

Sorry if my question is not clear. Please let me know if you want me to provide any clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the positive label. For example if you want -1 to be your positive label, you'll call

```
recall_score(y_true=[...], y_pred=[...], pos_label=-1)
```

Note by default 1 is the positive label.

Comment: Thanks @kshikama. Say if I am using unsupervised SVM model for my classification and the label outcome is either 1 or -1, is that outcome based on whether the model thinks an email is outlier vs non-outlier? If this true, is '1' considered non-outlier and '-1' considered outlier?

Comment: So if its unsupervised you only know that the groups are related within. If you know more details about your data set, then you might be able to figure out. For example if you know you have more "non-outliers" (I guess that is so by definition), then you could just say the label with more data points assigned to it is the "non-outliers" group.